# @ionic/storage-angular is not working on android?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-storage

I have been stock for an hours because of this issue on @ionic/storage-angular it seems that its not working on android?

In my case it work fine on browser the data was stored in the IndexedDB. but when I going to run the app in the physical device(USB debugging) the storage is not working.

After googling I still can't find a related thread the same on the issue that I am currently facing.

Maybe anyone have an idea? Please share your thoughts. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code..

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class StorageService {

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    await this.storage.create();
  }

  async set(key: string, value: any) {
    const encryptedData = btoa(escape(JSON.stringify(value)));
    return await this.storage.set(key, encryptedData)
  }
  
  async get(key: string) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.storage.get(key).then((value) => {
        if(value == null) {
          resolve(false);
        } else {
          resolve(JSON.parse(unescape(atob(value))))
        }
      })
    })
  }

  async removeItem(key: string) {
    await this.storage.remove(key);
  }

  async clear() {
    await this.storage.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: if you are using capacitor use this: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/storage

Comment: Post your code so we can help you.

Comment: Hi @NajamUsSaqib I added the code please check above

Comment: Hi @RobertCojocaru I added the code please check above

Comment: There is nothing strange, you should connect the device to Android Studio and check the `logcat` to see if it throws any error

Comment: @RobertCojocaru Yup totally fine in the browser also the issue is in the android device. how can we run ionic project in android studio?

Comment: Just plug the device to USB port and open Android Studio, then open the logcat tab and you will see logs from all the system, there is an dropdown where you can filter logs only from your app

Comment: Also, you can open the entire proyect with android studio and install the app from there

Comment: @RobertCojocaru Yup Im running on a physical device by usb debuging. and run using this command `ionic cordova run android -l` in my project fine in vs code terminal

Comment: if there is error in android it will show in android studio?

Comment: It will show a lot of logs, you have to read it carefully to see if there is an error. Use `console.log` to identify it quickly

Comment: Debug -> app -> console (right?)

Comment: View > Tool Windows > Logcat. Using version Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1